# Passing an Array of String to a Method doesn't Update every string in Label Text

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods, parameters, uilabel

Help me to Solve this ..
actually I have an array of strings.
Im passing those array as Parameter to another Method, where those string are printed in a label..
The Issue is Im only getting the Last Index of the array in the Label..
what should I need to do , For displaying Every Index String in Label?

```
-(void)method{
       NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",@"six",@"seven",@"eight",@"nine",@"ten", nil];
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array[i]];
        [self setTextForLoader:temp];


    }
  }
+(void)setTextForLoader:(NSString*)loaderStr{

    NSLog(@"loaderStr-->%@",loaderStr);

   [activityViewLabel setText:@""];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"Syncing",loaderStr];

    [activityViewLabel setText:str];
    Sleep(1);

 }
```

Comment: Are you want to display all array value in one label or different label ?

Comment: @YatishAgrawal in single Label

Comment: NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@" %@,@"Syncing", activityViewLabel.text, loaderStr];. Actually what happen with you your label text is replace with another array value during the iteration and then last index value is store into the label.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this. The problem is you are calling `sleep` method on your `main` thread.

For calling your method.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Do background work
        [self method];
});
```

And your `setTextForLoader` method like this.

```
-(void)setTextForLoader:(NSString*)loaderStr{

    NSLog(@"loaderStr-->%@",loaderStr);

    [_labelTimer setText:@""];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",@"Syncing",loaderStr];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [_labelTimer setText:str];
    });


    sleep(1);

}
```

Comment: Im Getting correct str in my Console, but I cant get any changes in my Label.
Actually it shows only last index String in my Label.

Comment: Yes I have tried ur code.Actually the thing is, I get the values from a API.
From API i Save into Array and my For loop looks like 
`for (NSDictionary *categoryDictionary in responseObject[@"XX"][@"YY"])`

Comment: The problem in your code is you called sleep method on your main thread because of this your UI does not update. so you need your sleep method on a background thread and you should always update your UI on main thread. It does not matter how you get data but you should have data in array when you called the for loop. in your method.